# Overwrite bootstrap div's padding

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap I have 2 divs, one div contains label and the other contain input :

```
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-3 float-left div1">
        <label class="control-label">Label</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 float-left div2">
        <input class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
```

The 2 divs have side padding because of bootstrap col-sm-XX, so the space between each field is 30px (15px for col-sm-3 and 15px col-sm-9).

My issue is that I want to keep the space between the 2 fields, but the background color of the first div to be right next to the input.

Actually I have this : [image]

And what I want would be this : [image]

And to keep the 30px spacing between label and input. [I have plunkered my issue](https://plnkr.co/edit/GOeMmpyrbHYpedm8vbNx?p=preview).

Comment: <div class="col-sm-3 float-left div1" style="padding-right:0"> ......

<div class="col-sm-9 float-left div2" style="padding-left:0"> .....

Comment: @FurkanKolcu : like this I do not keep the 30px space between the 2 div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `30px` padding to the right of `div1` and set the the left padding of `div2` to `0` see your **[Edited Plucker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MTFeLe8mTU0jVLamp5ez?p=preview)**.

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css);
/* Styles go here */
.float-left {
  float: left;
}
.div1 {
  background: red;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.div2 {
  // background: blue;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-3 float-left div1">
        <label class="control-label">Label</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 float-left div2">
        <input class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the 15px padding from div2 and add it to div1

```
.div1 {
  padding: 0 30px 0 15px;
}
.div2 {
  padding: 0;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZjqN9yFjjHqDNjGomKZr?p=preview